# How can I change the length of an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, dynamic-arrays

So I am assigned with a project where I have an array.
As the user puts elements into this array **it will have to double in length once it gets full**.

*We are **not permitted to use ArrayLists** or anything in the **collections interface**.*

What I was trying to do was to **make a new array**, once the old array was full, and then **copy the values to the new array**.

The problem is I don't know how many times I will have to make a new array, so I was wondering how to go about solving this.

Comment: Any hints about the development environment?

Comment: You missed a minor detail: what language are you using? Or you are free to choose? :)

Comment: It depends upon the programming language. C++ has [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)... Please edit your question to improve it (and give some of your source code)

Comment: sorry I forgot that major detail. I'm working with java

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are fixed length. If you want a data structure that has variable length use an ArrayList

Comment: I am not allowed to use array lists

Comment: See my other answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Since the poster explicitly stated the requirements of the homework exclude the use of Collections an alternative approach would be to use System.arraycopy(). In such an approach you only maintain a single array and as you add items to it you use System.arraycopy() to copy the old array into a new larger array. System.arraycopy() is relatively fast and is actually how ArrayList expands its size.

If you are concerned about the cost of using System.arraycopy() you could use it only when your array is full and create a new array with more space. E.g.
Create and array of size 20. When it gets full copy it into and array of size 40. When that gets full copy it into an array of size 60...

Interestingly ArrayList increases its size by

```
int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;
```

when the old array is full. Presumably the writers of this put some considerable thought into how much to grow the array by when needed. It might be worth doing the same.